# Web application framework that suports 3D

Tags: webgl

I have an idea to develop a website that would help people to model 3D worlds, use 3D models and so on.

For example, based on my reseach, I could use Unity Framework to create this type of application for PC/MAC.

I am wondering if there are similar frameworks available for pure WEB?

This is my first time looking into this and I do not have any expertize in this topic. Please advise if you have any opinions or expertise in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity indeed has support for 3d on web, but it requires from user that it has installed Unity player. Users might not like that.

However, with webGL, you would have absolute control over the look and capabilities of your product, users wouldn't have to install anything new, it would all be pure web and only IE users would be damaged, because IE still doesn't have full support for webGL.

To develop with webGL you can do it from scratch, or you could use some of the existing libraries/3D engines that would speed up your work and give results much faster.

Here's a list of webGL engines: http://ffwd.typepad.com/blog/2011/04/webgl-what-flavor-is-your-engine.html, it seems that most used are Three.js, Scene.js and there is also Goo Engine (http://www.gooengine.com/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out 3DTin, it does seem to deliver a part of what you want to build, using WebGL:

http://www.3dtin.com/